# Как присвоить переменную значению указателя

Tags: c

есть указатель `*N`;  `N="it's a good weather today"; char A[100];`
Как присвоить значение `A` `N` или просто как вывести на консоль `N`?

Answer (score 4):

Если у вас имеется указатель, адресующий строковый литерал

```
char *N; 
N = "it's a good weather today";
```

и символьный массив

```
char A[100];
```

то, чтобы скопировать строковый литерал в символьный массив, вам следует использовать стандартную C функцию `strcpy`, объявленную в заголовке `<string.h>` . Например,

```
#include <string.h>

//...

strcpy( A, N );
```

при условии, что размер массива достаточен, для размещения в нем строкового литерала. В противном случае следует использовать функцию `strncpy`

```
#include <string.h>

//...

strncpy( A, N, sizeof( A ) );
A[sizeof( A ) - 1] = '\0';
```

После этого вы можете вывести строку на консоль, как, например,

```
puts( A );
```

или

```
printf( "%s\n", A );
```